# Display the items in the cart in a jsp file from servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am building a E-Commerce simple solution in java and i am stucked in a critical point. I am not able to display the correct items. I am using a servlet that has a doGet a shoppingcart class, a products class and viewcart.jsp file. To pass the items between servlets  i am using the setAttribute of context. Here are my files i have build so far. Can anyone help me fix this problems? Every time i press add to car it adds the element but look like all the previous elements get overwritten by the last one i added.

```
package com.kd.ecommerce;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class addtocart
 */
@WebServlet("/addtocart")
public class addtocart extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private shoppingcart shop = new shoppingcart();

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    ServletContext thisContext = getServletContext(); 
    String name = request.getParameter("product");
    Connection cn = DBConnect.getInstance();
    try {
        Statement st = cn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from inventory where name = '"+name+"' LIMIT 1");
        while(rs.next()){
            Products p = new Products(rs.getString(2),rs.getString(3),rs.getString(4),rs.getFloat(5));
            System.out.println(p.getName()+":"+ p.getPrice());
            shop.ins(p);
            thisContext.setAttribute("shop", shop.getIt());
            for(int i = 0; i< shop.getIt().size(); i++){
                System.out.println(shop.getIt().get(i)+":"+ shop.getIt().get(i).getPrice());
            }
            response.sendRedirect("inventory.jsp?addedto=success");
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

}

}
```

Products.java

```
package com.kd.ecommerce;

public class Products {
private static String name;
private static Float price;
private static String desc;
private static String img;

public Products(String n, String d, String i,Float p){
    name = n;
    price = p;
    desc = d;
    img = i;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public Float getPrice(){
    return price;
}

public String getImage(){
    return img;
}

public String getDesc(){
    return desc;
}
}
```

shoppingcart.java

```
package com.kd.ecommerce;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class shoppingcart {
private static ArrayList<Products> items;

public shoppingcart(){
    items = new ArrayList<Products>();
}

public void ins(Products p){
    items.add(p);
}

public void remove(Products p){
    items.remove(p);
}

public int getSize(){
    return items.size();
}

public ArrayList<Products> getIt(){
    return items;
}
}
```

viewcart.jsp

```
<jsp:include page="menu.jsp"></jsp:include>
<% 
ServletContext sc = getServletConfig().getServletContext();
if(sc.getAttribute("shop") != null){
    ArrayList<Products> it = (ArrayList<Products>)sc.getAttribute("shop");
    out.println(it);
    for(int i = 0; i< it.size(); i++){
        out.println("<span class='price'>"+it.get(i).getPrice()+"</span>");
    }
}else{
    out.println("<span class='empty'>Shopping cart empty</span>");
}
%>
```

-- EDIT --

My new viewcart.jsp using sessions

```
<% 
if(session.getAttribute("shop") != null){
    shoppingcart sh = (shoppingcart)session.getAttribute("shop");
    ArrayList<Products> pd = sh.getIt();
    for(int i = 0; i< pd.size(); i++){
        out.println("<span class='price'>"+pd.get(i).getPrice()+"</span>");
    }
}else{
    out.println("<span class='empty'>Shopping cart empty</span>");
}
%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's causing your problem is that you have made the **shoppingcart** an instance variable in your Servlet. That means that every HTTP request that your Servlet handles is sharing the same **shoppingcart**.  To fix this, move the following line from the class definition code:

```
private shoppingcart shop = new shoppingcart();
```

And move it into the **doGet** method before the following line:

```
shop.ins(p);
```

The **doGet** method will then contain the following two lines:

```
shoppingcart shop = new shoppingcart();
shop.ins(p);
```

You may even consider giving the **shoppingcart** class a constructor that takes a **Products** object as parameter and sets the items in the constructor. Then you could combine those two lines into one, as follows:

```
shoppingcart shop = new shoppingcart(p);
```

It's a common mistake to define objects as instance variables in Servlets. Just remember that every HTTP call to your servlet will share the instance variables. If you're wanting to store information for specific users, consider putting them in the session.

----EDIT----

I didn't actually answer the question, as it turns out. To keep a running tally of the added items, you have to save the items to a place that will not be shared by anyone--a place only the specific user will have his data saved to. The session is the place that was specifically designed for this purpose. You can use the session like this in your **doGet** method:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
shoppingcart shop = (shoppingcart)session.getValue("shop");
if(shop == null) {
    shop = new shoppingcart();
    session.putValue("shop", shop);
}

shop.ins(p);
```

The line that gets the value from the session returns whatever object is stored with the key "shop". If this is the first item the user is adding, no shopping cart will have been saved yet, so **shop** will be **null**. That's why we do the null check; to create a shopping cart and then associate it with the "shop" key so that the next time the user adds an item, a shopping cart will have been associated with the key "shop".

Once we have a **shoppingcart** that is associated with the "shop" key for that particular user, you should see the items being added to that same cart object as multiple submissions are made.

Comment: But in this case the shopping cart has always 1 item as i am initializing each time a new shopping cart. How can i initialize once the shopping cart and keep adding elements to it?

Comment: Sorry, Leon, you're right. I edited my answer up above to explain using sessions, which should fully answer your question. Let me know if that made sense or not.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I just wanted to say that i implemented it with sessions and now every time i add a product it increments the number of products in the cart but shows me always the price of the last product added. Lets say i have 3 products and the last one has price 10, i will see 3 10s in my cart. Its is overwriting the previous values. I don't understand as the logic you have in your code makes total sense.

Comment: The problem is actually in your **Products** class. You've made all of your instance variables **static**. What this means is that all instances of **Products** will share those variables. That's not what you want--you want them each to have their own data. To do that, simply remove the **static** keyword from all of your instance variables in **Products**.

Comment: That did the Trick. I didn't even pay attention to the product class. Thanks a lot.